# Don't know why my while loop doesn't work (Java) ..?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

The purpose of my code is to enter a pin, and it'll check if it's right or not. If it isn't, the question will loop. 
For some reason, my code doesn't loop properly, and a lot of the code is underlined. Specifically the while loop itself and the second JOptionPane

```
// package loop;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class loop {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int correctPin = 3333; 
    int count = 0;
    String maybePin = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the PIN"); 
    int sMaybePin = Integer.parseInt(maybePin); 
    while(correctPin != sMaybePin);{ 
       maybePin = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the PIN"); 

       count = count-1; 
}
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, count);
}
}
```

Comment: remove the semicolon:
`while(correctPin != sMaybePin){`

Comment: Also, I believe `maybePin = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the PIN");` in the while loop is wrong.  You need to be assigning to sMaybePin instead.

Comment: Your other real problem is that sMaybePin will never change its value, as changing that string maybePin does not affect that int value parsed EARLIER on. Besides your names only add to the confusion here!

Answer (score 1):

```
 while(correctPin != sMaybePin); <--
```

Look at that `;` that terminates the loop right there. You need to remove that.

Comment: Err. Did you notice the values he is comparing?he is missing to reparse the int value!

Answer (score 1):

You never update `sMabyPin` which is the variable you are checking against. If you do what @John and @ANS suggested you'll be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Looks like you were the first one to solve the puzzle :-) so p1 too; although your answer currently reads more like a mediocre comment.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ; after the while statement and correct set the value of the variable sMaybePin to the input vlaue and ot works

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int correctPin = 3333;
    int count = 0;
    String maybePin = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the PIN");
    int sMaybePin = Integer.parseInt(maybePin);
    while(correctPin != sMaybePin){
        sMaybePin = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the PIN"));

        count = count-1;
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, count);
}
```

Comment: hmm this doesn't work 
I can't change maybePin to sMaybe because sMaybe is a int value 
int can't be used with JOptionPane

Comment: JOptionPane returns a String. I cast this String with Integer.parseInt to a int.

Comment: Your the one figuring that the int value needs to be reparsed! P1 for that.